# Caps lock to change input language disabled by Spotify.app

Tags: macos, spotify

I use caps lock to change input language, but when Spotify.app is ON caps lock behaves like normal caps lock.

Any ideas how to get def macOS functionality back? I looked through Spotify.app settings and couldn't find key mapping options.

Comment: You should contact Spotify.  I see another complaint from months ago at  https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac/Switching-between-quot-input-sources-quot-with-using-quot-Caps/td-p/1452332 .  In meantime, you can always go back to the standard Control plus Space shortcut.

Comment: @TomGewecke I already contacted them. I'd rather quit spotify app than rebind keys in my brain :)

Comment: I think you have your priorities correct there.

Comment: The problem seems to be streaming/music app related as the same occurs with Amazon Music streaming.